# WaitForSeconds in Coroutine not working as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want the bullet to start a Coroutine in the enemy script, which damages the enemy every second by a float given to the enemy script from the bullet, until it reaches 0 hp and destroys itself. For some reason the "Poisoning" process works until the waitforseconds place. Do I miss something?

When testing debug.log("STEP ONE") is always reached without any problems. But "Poisoned" after the WaitForSecond moment is never reached. I do not have any other errors. The Bullet script works perfectly fine for non Poisonous bullets.

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
...

    public IEnumerator Poisoned(float HpPerSecond)
    {
        Debug.Log("STEP ONE");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        Debug.Log("Poisoned");
        TakeDamage(HpPerSecond);
        StartCoroutine(Poisoned(HpPerSecond));
    }
...
}
```

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool Poisonous = false;
    public float PoisonDamagePerSecond;
    Coroutine poison = null;
...
    void DamageTarget()
    {
    ...
    if (Poisonous)
        {
            poison = StartCoroutine(target.GetComponent<Enemy>().Poisoned(PoisonDamagePerSecond));
        }
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Comment: The enemy should start it's coroutine by itself not by other script for best practice, probably you destroy your bullet and the coroutine stops without killing the enemy.

Comment: I use Object Pool for bullets. It never gets destroyed. The coroutine gets called was earlier than the "Destruction". The Problem ist that the coroutine gets called but stops at the WaitForSeconds moment. So the bullet is probably not the problem.

Comment: İf you disable the object for pooling it, the coroutine will disable as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand about coroutines.
Check out the official documentation at the [following link.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

```
void DamageTarget()
{
...
if (Poisonous)
    {
        poison = StartCoroutine(target.GetComponent<Enemy>().Poisoned(PoisonDamagePerSecond));
    }
...
}
```

Coroutines run in MonoBehaviour by default.
If you write the code as above, the coroutine is executed in `Bullet`.
When `Bullet` is disabled or destroyed the coroutine stops.

Try working in the form below.

> `Enemy`

```
public void StartPoisoned(float HpPerSecond)
{
    StartCoroutine(Poisoned(HpPerSecond));
}
```

> `Bullet`

```
void DamageTarget()
{
...
if (Poisonous)
    {
        target.GetComponent<Enemy>().StartPoisoned(PoisonDamagePerSecond));
    }
...
}
```